# Mapping HttpRequests

Tags: java, http, servlets, jakarta-ee, networking

I have a queue which is not under my control that fires an HTTPrequest every 1 minute if it does not receive a response for the previously fired request. My HTTP request internally performs a sequence of operations that exceeds one minute and would give a response after a minute.

EDIT: A side effect of this is, when the second request arrives when the first request is already executing. The second request returns with a  failure as it is blocked by the first request and when the original request completes it returns with a success.

The queue which is not under my control is tied to a ui element which shows success or failure. So what happens now is that, once triggered, a failure status is shown first, as a result of the response of the second request which returns quicker as it fails early and then the success as a result of the original request being completed successfully.

A hypothetical solution to this would be to map any new HTTP request to the currently executing HTTP request. Since they would share the same memory location, the request would return a response only when it finishes executing.

Can this be achieved in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You need to works asynchronously and save intermediate data to a database.

Here is a possible pseudo code:

```
// Servlet code

receive requestX
requestOnDatabase = loadFromDatabase(requestX);
if (requestOnDatabase) {
   if (requestOnDatabase.state == FINISHED) {
       return requestOnDatabase.result;
   } else {
       return NOT_YET_FINISHED;
   }
} else {
   requestX.state = NEW_REQUEST;
   addToDatabase(requestX);
   startThread(requestX);
} 
return NOT_YET_FINISHED;


// Asynchronous thread
...
requestX.result = ...
requestX.state = FINISHED;
saveOnDatabase(requestX);
```

This kind of code will start the asynchronous thread and returns a code that said only that the request has been taken and the process is started but not finished.

Any successive request will check the status on the database and returns the current status if not yest finished.

Finally after the end of the asynchronous thread any successive request will return the result saved on the database.

This can be explained with the following schema

```
 Servlet                   Asynchronous thread        Database
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 First Request received
 Request not present on db
 Create new record on db
                                                      request.state = NEW_REQUEST
 Starts new thread
                            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            Thread started
 returns NEW_REQUEST


 ....

 Second Request received
 Request present on db
 returns NEW_REQUEST     

 ...

 Request received
 Request present on db
 returns NEW_REQUEST    

                          request.state = FINISHED
                          request.result = XXX
                          saveToDb(request)
                          end of asynchronous thread
                          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

                                                         request.state = FINISHED
                                                         request.result = XXX

 ...

 Third Request received
 Request present on db
 returns request.result


 ...

 Fourth Request received
 Request present on db
 returns request.result
```

Comment: The new request arrives when the current request is being processed. Hence, what would happen is that the new incoming request  will return a failure and then the original request completes which returns a success code.

Comment: Both original and new request will fail. A  third request after the completion of asynchronous thread will work. Generally every request received before the end of asynchronous thread fail, any request after the end of asynchronous thread works

Comment: The queue which is not under my control is tied to a ui element which shows success or failure. So what happens now is that, once triggered, a failure status is shown first, as a result of the response of the second request which returns quicker as it fails early and then the success as a result of the original request being completed successfully.

Comment: I was looking for a way to map the incoming request to the original request such that when i get a success response for the original request the second request also returns a success.